# What's the most efficient way to determine whether a new observation is unique or the repeat of a previous one?

Tags: design-patterns

I'm building a knowledgebase site and for each page in the knowledgebase I'd like to be able to show the following statistic: ***Viewed X times by Y diferent people***

**Calculating the number of views is trivial**

In order to count the total number of views I can simply increment a page view counter each time the page is loaded (users are logged in so there are no spamming issues etc).

**The naive approach to unique page views - store all viewer IDs**

In order to decide whether to count a fresh visit as a new unique visitor or one of the previous visitors simply returning again I need a record of who has already seen the page.

This means keeping a store of previous visitor IDs to each page. Each time a visitor arrives I check whether their ID exists in the store. If it does I do nothing and if it doesn't I append it. Meanwhile I keep a tally of the total number of unique IDs.

**Storing and looking up against all IDs to calculate a single total feels janky**

This is programatically very simple to do but feels ugly. The idea of storing many IDs and then doing a lookup for each new ID simply to calculate a single integer feels like something more clever minds than mine have found a compact solution to.

**Is this a standard problem pattern?**

What is the most efficient way to determine whether a new observation is unique or pre-existing?

I'm interested in whether this is a standard problem with some compact solution involving hashing or similar?

***NB my interest is whether there is some smart maths or algorithm for doing this. I can solve it I just suspect there's a smarter way...***

Comment: +1 interesting question.  I don't know whether there's a "clever" solution, but with the "naive" solution, the number of records is at most N*P where (N is number of users, and P is number of pages).  And fast lookup should be possible with hash-tables or similar.

Comment: Why is it ugly, and why doesn't it scale? Provided you have an index on [userID, page], your database will find the record very quickly. That said, users usually don't care about those statistics. Only the web site owner does. Have you considered using Google Analytics or a similar service?

Comment: @JBNizet - it does scale for my purposes but imagine the case where you've got a page trending on Hacker News or similar and receiving are 100 views per second. Keeping a tally of all 10,000 ultimate views and checking each one for uniqueness is less than idea. Definitely do-able especially if you make the processing asynchronous but feels janky...

Comment: If you have so many users and page views, getting and incrementing a counter in the database is probably not the biggest of your problems. And indeed, a cache ans some asynchronicity will make the process faster. Anyway, if you want to count "unique" page views, I don't see any other solution.

Comment: @JBNizet - I agree that it's not the hard part of such a problem, I was just interested in the design pattern - the fastest way to compute whether a new observation is unique or repeated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just thinking out loud here, but let's see if this makes sense algorithmically:

For every page, store three fields:

- one view counter, as you already have
- one "unique viewer" counter
- one "bloom filter" (basically a big bit field, but google up implementation details)

When a user hits the page, generate the hash for that user. If that hash is already in the bloom filter, just bump the view counter

If it's not in the bloom filter, bump both counters and add that hash to the filter. There is a possibility for false positives (but never false negatives) in the bloom filter membership check depending on your hash, however, so be careful about how you choose the hashing algorithm.

Three fields. Not too bad. :)

Ref:[Bloom Filter on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter)

EDIT: I've had this code floating around for a while - not sure where the core came from initially, but I've tweaked it over the years - ready for LINQPad:

```
void Main()
{
    var estimatedCount = 100000;
    var falsePositiveProbability = 0.001;
    var falsePositiveCount = 0;
    var memberCount = 0;
    var bloom = BloomFilter<char>.Create(
        estimatedCount, 
        falsePositiveProbability,
        c => c.GetHashCode(),
        c => (int)c);
    var allChars = Enumerable.Range(0, 0xffff).Select(i => (char)i).ToList();
    foreach(var c in allChars)
    {
        var alreadyIn = bloom.Test(c);
        if(alreadyIn)
        {
            falsePositiveCount++;
        }
        bloom.Add(c);
        memberCount++;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Predicted count: {0} Predicted false positive: {1:p} ", estimatedCount, falsePositiveProbability);
    Console.WriteLine("Actual false positive count: {0} Actual member count: {1} ", falsePositiveCount, memberCount);
    Console.WriteLine("False positive rate: {0:p}", ((double)falsePositiveCount / memberCount));
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public class BloomFilter<TValue>
{
    private BitArray hashbits;
    private int numKeys;

    private Func<TValue,int> _hashFunc1;
    private Func<TValue,int> _hashFunc2;

    public static BloomFilter<TValue> Create(int estimateCount, double falsePositiveRate, Func<TValue,int> hash1, Func<TValue,int> hash2)
    {
        // formulae courtesy of http://hur.st/bloomfilter
        var tableSize = Math.Ceiling((estimateCount * Math.Log(falsePositiveRate)) / Math.Log(1.0 / (Math.Pow(2.0, Math.Log(2.0)))));
        var keyCount = Math.Round(Math.Log(2.0) * tableSize / estimateCount);
        return new BloomFilter<TValue>((int)tableSize, (int)keyCount)
        {
            _hashFunc1 = hash1,
            _hashFunc2 = hash2
        };
    }

    private BloomFilter(int tableSize, int nKeys)
    {
        numKeys = nKeys;
        hashbits = new BitArray(tableSize);
    }

    public bool Test(TValue val)
    {
        var hashKeys = GenerateHashes(val);
        foreach (int hash in hashKeys)
        {
            if (!hashbits[hash])
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public bool Add(TValue val)
    {
        bool rslt = true;
        var hashKeys = GenerateHashes(val);
        foreach (int hash in hashKeys)
        {
            if (!hashbits[hash])
            {
                rslt = false;
                hashbits[hash] = true;
            }
        }
        return rslt;
    }

    private int[] GenerateHashes(TValue val)
    {
        int hash1 = _hashFunc1(val);
        int hash2 = _hashFunc2(val);

        var hashKeys = new int[numKeys];

        hashKeys[0] = Math.Abs(hash1 % hashbits.Count);
        if (numKeys > 1)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < numKeys; i++)
            {
                hashKeys[i] = Math.Abs((hash1 + (i * hash2)) %
                    hashbits.Count);
            }
        }
        return hashKeys;
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this a lot, thank you and it's right in the zone. A friend had just suggested to me to look at Bloom filters. As far as I understand they're extremely fast wrt searching but I wasn't sure whether you could just "increment" the filter to include the new hash. Can the filter be "grown" without the original dataset and if so is it fast to grow it? Since it's happening fewer times it could always be async but I wanted to get an idea of the cost of computing and adding a new hash to the filter

Comment: @PeterNixey Simplifying considerably, it's basically: 1. compute hash 2. for each bit in hash, set corresponding bit in bloom filter (if bit is set, that is - no clearing bits allowed).

Comment: apologies, I'm not sure my question was clear (or else I didn't properly understand your answer). What I meant was can the bloom filter be created and then subsequently added to or does the full set need to be known at the time of creation?

Comment: @PeterNixey Yes, you can create it without knowing the full final membership - think of it this way: Say your hashes are three bits (you only have six members, say, allowing for 0 == nobody); user 5 comes in, hash is 101 - you pull the zero, compare the bits you have, see no match. Now you add '101' to the set, basically or'ing in the 1s. Now filter is '101'. User 3 comes in, '101' & '011' != '011', so not there. Add '011' to hash - now in this stupid example, we can see the false positives problem, as now the filter is '111', matching anyone. Hence, choose a hashing scheme VERY carefully.

Comment: @PeterNixey Re: the false positive thing, to avoid this, you have multiple hash functions, one for each bit of the filter - so if we had a filter of 3 bits, we'd have 3 distinct hashes we'd generate to check membership.

Comment: Awesome - thank you. My project now is to go off and learn about bloom filters

Comment: @PeterNixey You're in luck, I found a bloom filter in my personal library :) - it's in C#, so you'd need to translate accordingly

Answer (score 0):

In this case, a relational database may not be the most efficient or the most scalable way to solve this. I'd suggest looking at key-value store, like perhaps Redis - http://redis.io in which the key can be the page identifier, and the value can be a set backed by a hash table - see http://redis.io/commands#set

Comment: If I have to take the basic approach I think you're almost definitely right. I'm interested though whether there's an alternative algorithmic solution that doesn't involve storing the previous observations